# Symfony 4 access parameters inside of repository

Tags: php, symfony, repository

I have a repository class called EmailRepository

```
class EmailRepository extends EntityRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface { ... }
```

I need to get a parameter injected into this repository class but I dont know how...

This is what I currently have inside of the repository, which is being called from my controller:

**Controller:**

```
$em->getRepository(Email::class)->getEmailApi();
```

**Repository**

```
class EmailRepository extends EntityRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface {    

     protected $container;
     public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null) {
         $this->container = $container;
     }

     /**
      * @param $array
      */
     public function getEmailApi($array)
     {

         echo $this->container->getParameter('email_api');
     }
}
```

I always get this error:

```
 Call to a member function getParameter() on null
```

**The parameter is not null, it does have a value.** I know it's telling me that $this->container is null. How do I fix this?

If I run this inside of my controller, it works fine and returns **Google**

```
 echo $this->getParameter('email_api');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is not going to work because there is nothing calling EmailRepository::setContainer.  Furthermore, using ContainerAware and injecting the full container is discouraged.

Fortunately, the Doctrine bundle has a new base repository class that the entity manager can use to pull the repository from container and allow you to inject additional dependencies as needed.  Something like:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Email;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class EmailRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository // Different class to extend from
{
    private $emailApi;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Email::class);

        $this->emailApi = $parameterBag->get('email_api');

    }
```

So in this case we inject all the parameters and then store the ones we need.

Even injecting the parameter bag is a bit frowned upon.  Better to inject individual parameters though this takes just a bit more configuration as we need to use services.yaml to explicitly inject the needed parameters:

```
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, string $emailApi)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Email::class);

        $this->emailApi = $emailApi;

    }
#services.yaml
    App\Repository\EmailRepository:
        $emailApi: 'email_api_value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject container not a good idea. Try this

services.yaml

```
App\Repository\EmailRepository:
    arguments:
        $emailApi: '%env(EMAIL_API)%'
```

Repository

```
class EmailRepository
{    

     protected $emailApi;

     public function __construct(string $emailApi) 
     {
         $this->emailApi = $emailApi;
     }

     /**
      * @param $array
      */
     public function getEmailApi($array)
     {
         return $this->emailApi;
     }
}
```

Or via setter injection

services.yaml

```
App\Repository\EmailRepository:
    calls:
        - method: setEmailApi
          arguments:
               $emailApi: '%env(EMAIL_API)%'
```

Repository

```
class EmailRepository extends EntityRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface 
{    

     protected $emailApi;

     public function setEmailApi(string $emailApi) 
     {
         $this->emailApi = $emailApi;
     }

     /**
      * @param $array
      */
     public function getEmailApi($array)
     {
         return $this->emailApi;
     }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code is going to tell the entity manager to use the container to create the repository.